# TFTPboot using Uboot : TFTP server on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, u-boot, tftp

I have a TFTP server running on Windows-10 machine.
I am using MobaXterm it has TFTP server.

[image]

I tested client server running on same windows 10, machine, able to communicate.

```
TFTP -i 192.168.1.7 get test.txt
Transfer successful: 11 bytes in 1 second(s), 11 bytes/s
```

My TFTP server directory on windows is :--

**C:\S32G2_images**

[image]

My target board, using uboot i am trying to TFTPboot buts connection is not establishing with the TFTP server running on the windows 10 machine.

**Please suggest how to resolve this ?**

Target Board Uboot setting :--

[image]

PC, running windows-10 :--
[image]

Ping to TFTP server working from Uboot :--

[image]

trying to connect to TFTP server from Linux U-boot failing :--

[image]

Windows Firewall setting :--
[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying from uboot.

I also tried to run the **TFTP client from Linux booted onto my board.**

PFE-2 setting on LINUX booted on S32G2 ;--
[image]

I added Windows-10 machine to my routing table  :--
[image]

I am able to ping from Linux running on my board to windows-10 machine :--
[image]

I am able to ping from windows-10 machine to Linux running on my board  :--
[image]

TFTP client on my board is part of busybox package.

**But still same issue , not able to connect to tftp server on Windows-10** machine :--

[image]